# how to insert newline in string in c# after some particular digit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, algorithm

i was programming some code in which i have to enter text in a particular format only.
i.e.

```
2
10 5 kdsfj ejkd kjdf
7 8 sdkj dsjklf ckjsd dksj
```

and so on

but i have to enter the data form a text file having the whole as a string as

**`2 10 5 kdsfj ejkd kjdf7 8 sdkj dsjklf ckjsd dksj6 12 kjd ekjr fkjdr fdkj`**

but i want to suppy the text as given above format.
Bold letters are saparable points.
i want a program so that it can add a newline after character or space followed by digit ?

How can i do that ?

Comment: Why do you insert a newline between 2 and 10, but not between 10 and 5, nor between 7 and 8? Could you be more specific with your requirement?

Comment: @Douglas : sir i want to add newline between the string such as kjdf7 and dksj6 as shown above. here digits and chars are attached and i need to insert a newline between them

Comment: Why does 2 end up on its own line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is going to be some form of regex

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"([A-Za-z])(\d)", "$1" + Environment.NewLine + "$2");
```

Where input is your source line from the file, and the pattern matches you specific criteria. With the above replace you end up with:

```
2 10 5 kdsfj ejkd kjdf
7 8 sdkj dsjklf ckjsd dksj
6 12 kjd ekjr fkjdr fdkj
```

Your additional comments clarified the line breaks when joined to a previous character; although I am still not sure why 2 ends up on its own line?

Comment: its not working in my case. i have used it as                         var ins  = textBox3.Text;
            string str = Regex.Replace(ins, @"([A-Za-z])(\d)", "$1" + Environment.NewLine + "$2");
           textBox2.Text = str;

Comment: I am unclear on the rule for why '2' has it's own line in your sample string, so that is currently not handled. Given your sample input string in the question you should get the same results as captured above. I tested in a sample C# application to confirm the results. Perhaps provide more detail on the results you are seeing?

Comment: @CalgaryCoder : Sir the 1st digit 2 shows no. of cases (coming lines with intially 5 8 as digits and then words) That's why i need to saparate them one in each line

Comment: @ItsLockedOut: So should your example string above really start with '3' given that there are three sets ('10 5', '7 8' and '6 12')?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; ++i)
  if (!s[i].IsDigit() && s[i+1].IsDigit())
    s.Insert(i+1, Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Hey i want to use it for a string STR = textBox3.Text; and then show the formatted string in another text box. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"([A-Za-z])(\d)", "$1" + Environment.NewLine + "$2");
```

Should do the trick, It'll match a series of characters, then a digit. Inserting a new line before the digit.

You'll have to use look-aheads or something for the case of that pesky 2.

Comment: Did you test your regex? Your replace is incorrect based on the pattern.

Comment: Rechecked with a different tool. Indeed, it is incorrect. Updated.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed Is that so? Then please provide a counterexample (except for the known leading 2)...